# How to delete the static value from the column by using Sql query in MS SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have some static value in the some columns in the table like below, how to remove only that value 'Hold_' from the column.

```
UserColumn
Hold_John
Hold_Smith
Hold_Evan
Jonny
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the REPLACE function:

```
Update testtable
Set UserColumn = Replace(UserColumn, 'Hold_', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

Using SUBSTRING(),CHARINDEX() also we can update that column

```
Update t
Set UserColumn =  SUBSTRING(UserColumn,CHARINDEX('_',UserColumn)+1,LEN(UserColumn))
from test t
```